# Google Sheet If-statement formula

Tags: google-sheets

I have a formula calculating a number :

```
F = SUMIFS(Besoins!$D$2:$D$999;Besoins!$C$2:$C$999;C$1;Besoins!$B$2:$B$999;$B5)
```

What I try to do then is to print either the result :

```
if F > 0, or "-" if F = 0
```

So I try with the IF function :

```
=IF(F=0;"-";?)
```

I don't know what to use to print the correct result when it is false. Anyone know how I could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot set a variable in a spreadsheet formula; that is, you cannot actually set the name `F` to your `SUM` expression there. You can either write:

```
=IF(SUM(Besoins!$D$2:$D$999;Besoins!$C$2:$C$999;C$1;Besoins!$B$2:$B$999;$B5)=0,"-",SUM(Besoins!$D$2:$D$999;Besoins!$C$2:$C$999;C$1;Besoins!$B$2:$B$999;$B5))
```

Or you could store `SUM(Besoins!$D$2:$D$999;Besoins!$C$2:$C$999;C$1;Besoins!$B$2:$B$999;$B5)` in one cell (for the sake of argument, cell A1) and in another cell, write:

```
=IF(A1=0,"-",A1)
```